# view.GONE in Recyclerview still keeps space

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I searched on the web and fount that there's a difference between view.invisible and view.gone, the vie.gone must disappear without keeping the space but it doesn't happen to me, how can I fix it? please help, check out the links of the two pictures.

Picture of the result on the Android Emulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC1Xr.png

Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwhno.png

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyReading, MyReadingViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <MyReading, MyReadingViewHolder>
            (
            MyReading.class,
            R.layout.list_reading,
            MyReadingViewHolder.class,
            mQuery )

    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MyReadingViewHolder viewHolder, MyReading model, int position) {

            final String wordNote_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setWord(model.getWord());
            viewHolder.setNote(model.getNote());


            mDatabase.child(wordNote_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String currentUid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();

                    if(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(currentUid)){

                      viewHolder.nView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        viewHolder.nView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.nView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent singleIntent = new Intent(WordNote.this, HandleWordNote.class);
                    singleIntent.putExtra("listWords", wordNote_key);
                    startActivity(singleIntent);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    listWN.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code (you can edit the question and copy-paste the code in) and the pictures seem to be identical

Comment: Are you trying to remove the ViewHolder completely, or just modify it so that the so that a view inside is gone?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Hi, I dont want to remove it completely because in this project I have this problem when two users work in the same "area" so I have to separate their jobs through a query in fact as you can see on top there's "mQuery", look I get then the data from the databse which is this (String currentUid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();) so I can say if you are another user you cant watch the other user's job, but there's a background thing that doesnt go away with the View.GONE, please help me I am frustrated honestl; I updated the link of the pic on top of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Ok, so after seeing the updated image, I see the real problem. In your query, add the constraint to only return the data snapshot with the current user's uid. The problem is that even though your viewholder's view is `GONE`, the viewholder itself will still hold the position, since there is a model object for that position. Rather then hacking away the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, just filter out the data you don't want in the list by using your `Query` object that you pass in.

---

Have you tried notifying the adapter of the change? Just because you modified the child view, doesn't mean the adapter will automatically resize the viewHolder to the proper size.

```
mDatabase.child(wordNote_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String currentUid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();

        if(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(currentUid)){

          viewHolder.nView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.nView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        //Notify the adapter the viewholder at this position changed.
        notifiyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work, nothing changed, I really don't understand where's the problem.. I heard people using a layout params

Comment: The query is this: mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("book").equalTo(bookYouAreIn);     I'm using Firebase as a Database, by using this query if I click a different book, it opens then the book clicked, do you know what I mean? then I filtered through the user ID to choose what to hide

Comment: Can you post an example of the data structure you are trying to query?

Comment: I posted the link of the  Database in the question, check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwhno.png

Comment: Have you tried `mDatabase.orderByChild("book").equalTo(bookYouAreIn).equalTo("uid", firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid())` as your mQuery parameter? From the looks of it, you have the data and books annotated with the user's uid, so constraining to return only those with the users seems like the answer.

Comment: it gives me a mistake on .equalTo("uid", .. it says: Cannot resolve method 'equalTo(java.lang.string, java.lang. this is the problem to fix, this query but I dont know how to fix this query, do you?

Comment: we need to tell to the Database "AND" like in SQL

Comment: Are you using the latest release of the Firebase SDK? On their docs, they have docs for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#equalTo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: im using the lastest version but its not the real problem, im using the cardview for the graphic, might it be this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which you can set the height of the viewHolder's view to zero.

```
val layoutParamter = holder.mView.layoutParams
layoutParamter.height = 0
holder.mView.layoutParams = layoutParamter
```