# How do I Query this in Android Studio using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my software I need a Query, how do I Query 2 information from the Database?? I need the "uid" and "book", check the link for watching my Database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TSt6.png

```
listWN = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listReading);

    listWN.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    bookYouAreIn = getIntent().getStringExtra("book");

    firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String currentUserId = firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");

    mQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("book").equalTo(bookYouAreIn); **---> HOW DO I ADD HERE: AND mDatabase.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid());**

    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    if(!firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(currentUserId)){

        startActivity(new Intent(WordNote.this,LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_secondmenu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_addWords){

        Intent postIntent = new Intent(WordNote.this, PostActivity.class);
        postIntent.putExtra("bookToPost", bookYouAreIn);
        startActivity(postIntent);

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyReading, MyReadingViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <MyReading, MyReadingViewHolder>
            (
            MyReading.class,
            R.layout.list_reading,
            MyReadingViewHolder.class,
            mQuery )

    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MyReadingViewHolder viewHolder, final MyReading model, final int position) {

            final String wordNote_key = getRef(position).getKey();

           viewHolder.setWord(model.getWord());
           viewHolder.setNote(model.getNote());

          mDatabase.child(wordNote_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  String user = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
                  String bookNow = (String) dataSnapshot.child("book").getValue();

                  if(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(user)){

                      mDatabase.child(wordNote_key).orderByChild("uid").equals(user);
                  }
                  else {
                     viewHolder.nView.setVisibility(View.GONE); **--> IT DOESN'T GO AWAY, IT KEEPS STAYING AS A BLANK VIEW**


                  }


              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });

                    viewHolder.nView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent singleIntent = new Intent(WordNote.this, HandleWordNote.class);
                    singleIntent.putExtra("listWords", wordNote_key);
                    startActivity(singleIntent);

                }
            });

        }
    };

    listWN.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730834/skip-row-in-firebaserecycleradapter/44765210).

In your case, the field would be: `uid_book: "OKtUxSleCGbU0F_Pasqua"`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: excuse me sir I didn't get it, by the way, check this, that's why I thought to filter from Firebase but I have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705131/view-gone-in-recyclerview-still-keeps-space/44709261?noredirect=1#comment76436874_44709261

Comment: Please take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=5#t=9m02s). Hope you understand better how to query using to values. Is the same example as explained by me above.

Comment: okok I have understood, but how do I make it on Android studio? I create another Child in my database but how do I insert the uid and the book which the user created in one line?

Comment: It's very simple, just use `concatenation` when you are using `setValue()` method like this: yourRef.child("uid_book").setValue(uid + "_" + bookName);

Comment: Alex thank you so much it works finally !! I started studying Firebase recently and thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to hear that. So if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks